# SQL: Case When After Multiple Left Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL with a table called `students`.  I'm trying to add a column that indicates whether a student came from the US, Europe, South America, or none of those.  Specifically, I'd like to put a 0 in the column if none of those are true, 1 if US, 2 if Europe, 3 if South America.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT name,
CASE WHEN ... 
FROM original_table or
LEFT JOIN us_table us
ON or.student_id = us.student_id
LEFT JOIN europe_table eur
ON or.student_id = eur.student_id
LEFT JOIN south_america_table sa
ON or.student_id = sa.student_id
```

I'm having trouble with the `CASE WHEN` part.  I could just say something like "when the `id` column from the US table is not null and the other `id` columns (from Europe and South America) are null, record a 1.

Similarly, if the `id` column from the Europe table isn't null and the US and South America table's `id` columns are null, record a 2.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Testing each against `NULL` seems like the best way. Use `ELSE` for the `0` value.

```
CASE WHEN us.student_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
     WHEN eur.student_id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
     WHEN sa.student_id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
     ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty bad data structure, I think.  Generally, splitting up equivalent information (such as geography) into different tables is not a good data model.

I would simply use `exists`:

```
SELECT name,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM us_table us WHERE ot.student_id = us.student_id)
             THEN 1
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM europe_table eur WHERE ot.student_id = eur.student_id)
             THEN 2
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM south_america_table sa WHERE ot.student_id = sa.student_id)
             THEN 3
             ELSE 0
        END) as origin
FROM original_table ot;
```

I also changed the table alias to `ot` from `or`, because `or` is a reserved word.